# Caculate the average of list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have **list** contains 70000 Vetor (sublist with size of 50 int)

i want to retrun the average of this **list**

i try np.mean(**list**,axis=0) but it's so slow . it's take so much time without any result.

any other way to calculate this average ?

Example of my list:

```
lis =[[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 10, 5, 21, 14, 5, 19, 4, 21, 20, 18, 15, 9, 19, 9, 5, 13, 5, 13, 9, 12, 12, 5, 14, 1, 9, 18, 5, 19, 5, 3, 20, 9, 15, 14, 8, 1, 25, 8, 1, 19, 19, 1, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 4, 5, 12, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 16, 18, 9, 14, 3, 5, 13, 12, 25, 8, 9, 3, 8, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 4, 5, 12, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 1, 9, 14, 3, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 18, 15, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 12, 25, 3, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 12, 5, 7, 9, 1, 12, 1, 2, 15, 21, 5, 19, 19, 5, 4, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 1, 2, 4, 18, 1, 8, 13, 1, 14, 5, 2, 14, 15, 21, 26, 9, 4, 1, 14, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 19, 1, 1, 4, 2, 14, 15, 21, 1, 2, 9, 23, 1, 11, 11, 1, 19, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 10, 1, 12, 9, 12, 2, 5, 14, 8, 1, 9, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 19, 1, 11, 9, 14, 1, 2, 9, 14, 20, 5, 12, 8, 15, 21, 3, 5, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 4, 5, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 4, 5, 12, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 5, 12, 13, 1, 19, 19, 9, 18, 1, 1, 12, 11, 8, 1, 4, 18, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 19, 19, 19, 15, 21, 20, 9, 5, 14, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 4, 5, 18, 5, 21, 19, 19, 9, 20, 5, 5, 3, 15, 12, 5, 12, 1, 12, 12, 1, 25, 1, 3, 15, 21, 20, 13, 12, 25, 18, 1, 3, 8, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],...]
print np.mean(lis,axis=0)
```

Comment: Takes a fraction of a second for me. Are you sure all the sublists are size 50?

Comment: yes ,but i want to return the average list

Comment: like this : aver =[5.2 1.8 9 2 6.3  ... ]

Comment: What do you want to do with the list once you have it? I still don't understand what's taking so long.

Comment: @kabanus i'll use it in other function as a paramter

Comment: I'm starting to suspect there's something else going on here, like this code is part of a function that doesn't get called. Rereading, you said you don't get any printed output and that doesn't seem to be plausible if this is actually running.

Comment: @JohnColeman Because `[np.mean(ls) for ls in lis]` computes wrong (i.e., not what was asked) mean: it is equivalent to `np.mean(list, axis=1)` - wrong axis!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be faster, using [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) but in your case (if you don't cast it to numpy array) comprehension does the best job:

```
[(sum(x)*1.0)/len(x) for x in itertools.izip(*lis)]
```

The `*1.0` is due to python 2.x division.

```
lis = [[random.randint(1,50) for j in range(50)] for i in range(1400)]
%timeit np.mean(lis, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.67 ms per loop

%timeit [(sum(x)*1.0)/len(x) for x in itertools.izip(*lis)]
100 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
%timeit [(sum(x)*1.0)/len(x) for x in lis] #NOTE: equivalent to np.mean(lis,axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 660 µs per loop

lisnp = np.array(lis) 

%timeit np.mean(lisnp, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop

lisnp = np.array(lis, dtype=np.float64)

%timeit np.mean(lisnp, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 67.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: OP could get total mean with what they use by not setting the `axis`. I'm guessing OP did that on purpose.

Comment: I do not think vanilla python can be any faster than numpy. Did you experiment and compare?

Comment: @SelçukGülcan it can when numpy is operating on a list and not an array.

Comment: @SelçukGülcan I've added `%timeit` results from my machine

Comment: @zipa, roganjosh I see, np method has an overhead since it has to convert python list to its np.array. Thanks.

Comment: @SelçukGülcan Exactly, added the timing on `np.array` as well

Comment: If you do `lisnp = np.array(lis, dtype=np.float64)` you will get even faster `np.mean` evaluations. Please add timing comparison.

Comment: @AGNGazer It's just twice as fast :)

Comment: I know ... I just did not want to edit your answer with my timings (absolute values, that is)

Comment: Just curious, do you get the same/close results?

Comment: In Python 3 with `numpy` 1.12.1, I get: 1) `np.mean(lis)` - 3.01 ms; 2) `zip` - 884 µs; 3) no `zip` (axis=1) - 915 µs; 4) `np.mean(lisnp)` (int) - 80.4 µs; 5) `np.mean(lisnp)` (float64) - 48.6 µs.

Comment: One more thing. If input data are also float data (instead of ints) then conversion to the `numpy.ndarray` is significantly faster and so the first test timing reduces to 1.46 ms from 3.01 ms (on my machine).